# JavaParser extracting annotation parameter value

Tags: java, static, jersey, javaparser

I'm working on a project to parse jersey based annotations to build an request interaction graph between projects from java source code.

It's easy to parse and get info when everythink like that

```
@GET    
@Path("/parameter/{param}")
public Response getParam(@PathParam("param") String prm) {    

    String output = "Jersey say : " + prm;    
    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build(); 

}
```

I can extract values like **{Method:"GET", Path:"parameter/{param}"}**

Other case are

```
private static final PARAMETER_PATH="/parameter/{param}";

@GET    
@Path(PARAMETER_PATH)
public Response getParam(@PathParam("param") String prm) {    

    String output = "Jersey say : " + prm;    
    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build(); 

}
```

or

```
private static String PATH_VARIABLE_STR = "{param}";
private static PARAMETER_PATH = "/parameter/"+PATH_VARIABLE_STR;

    @GET    
    @Path(PARAMETER_PATH)
    public Response getParam(@PathParam("param") String prm) {    

        String output = "Jersey say : " + prm;    
        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build(); 

    }
```

In last two cases, I could not extract the real value.

How can I get the value of the variable while I'm working on static source code with javaparser, ast or etc.

I'm waiting for your suggestions.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The AST produced by JavaParser or other parsers does not calculate values. If you have `3 + 5` in your code, this is an addition, a parser will not have the logic to interpret it and conclude that that is equivalent to `8`. You would need to implement that logic yourself. You want to basically create an interpreter for Java. I would say you can easily do that for a couple of basic operations: consider literals, the basic 4 mathematical operations and not much more. Of course if you try to consider the whole Java language that thing would spiral out of control very quickly.

Disclaimer: I am a JavaParser contributor

Comment: Thanks Federico. I'm working on VariableDeclarator to extract variable name and value and add it to list with package name. At least I search the variable into the list with comparing package and names to get value. You said that there is no easy way to do this with parser. Ok if I need some logical operations I have to implement basic interpreter. Thanks a lot again.